# KQL Integration with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, kql, azure-resource-graph

I have been working with Azure Resource Graphs to explore resources and security recommendations over a subscription. However, I'd like to generate the Kusto Query Language (KQL) requests from local computer using VS Code. I've been doing some search over this topic however, I can't find a way to do so.

I have installed "Kusto Notebooks" extension, but it's not working or connected to Azure Resource Graph. I know that I can create requests in VS Code using Azure cli command "az graph query", but it requires some changes in the syntax and I don't want to change each query that I write or come across twice, one for VS Code and another for Azure Resource Graph. Therefore, I'd like to use the same syntax that I insert in Azure Resource Graph, locally. When I try to run a very simple query such in Kusto Notebook like this one to simply return the count number of my subscription:

*Resources

| summarize count()*

It returns the below message:

*Error loading preloads:

Could not find renderer*

[image]

I've come across this Github article explaining that, but I don't understand which directory should I open or where the files "azgraph_subguid.txt" & "azgraph_output.txt" exists. The link below refers to the article:

https://github.com/olileger/azure-resource-graph-helper

Note:

I installed "Kusto Language Server" VS code extension, but it requires to create a connection either using "Azure Data Explorer" or "Application Insights" and I don't have neither resources of them. I want to use Azure Resource Graph.

Can anyone help with that, plz

Thanks,